# How to fill textbox and click on button of new window in ChromiumWebBrowser WinForm

Tags: winforms, chromium, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I am using ChromiumWebBrowser in my windows form application. I have successfully submit the data in main window. But i am not able to fill text box and click on button in opened new window.

Below piece of code open the new window.

```
chromeBrowser.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementsByClassName('btn-hji-left btn-full-width')[0].click()");
```

This new window have two control one is text box and other one is button. Below code is for these two control.

```
if (e.HttpStatusCode == 200 && e.Url.StartsWith("url"))
        {
            chromeBrowser.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementById('fname').value= 'My First Name'");  //Submit data in this textbox
            chromeBrowser.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementById('next').click()");                  // click on next button
        }
```

This code is not working. Please help me. How can i achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: ExecuteScriptAsync is an extension method that executes against the main browser instance. Have a look at the source for a better understanding. You'll also need to read the CefSharp general usage guide on the wiki to get a better understanding. You'll probably need to implement ILoadHandler and in Loading state changed, check the IBrowser instance to see if IsPopup is true and IsLoading is false.

Comment: Before you ask, no I don't have time to provide a detailed example.

Comment: Thanks @amaitland I will look in to ...